# in Elixir: string formatting

Tags: format, erlang, elixir

I have a transform rule:

```
"0549$2"
```

How do I apply this rule to strings in an Elixir?
In ruby i use:

```
format("0549%2$s", *["88", "77"])
=> "054977"
```

In Elixir I write:

```
:io.format("0549%2$s", ["88", "77"])
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :io.format(#PID<0.54.0>, "0549%2$s", ["88", "77"])
```

Because :io.format from erlang does not understand this format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to replace all `$` followed by an integer with the corresponding element (indexed from 1) of a list? Here's one way using `Regex.replace/3`:

```
defmodule A do
  def format(string, list) do
    Regex.replace(~r/\$(\d+)/, string, fn _, index ->
      Enum.at(list, String.to_integer(index) - 1)
    end)
  end
end

IO.inspect A.format("0549$2", ["88", "77"])
IO.inspect A.format("0549$1", ["88", "77"])
```

Output:

```
"054977"
"054988"
```

Answer (score 4):

You might use [`:io_lib.format/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#format-2). It produces the charlist, that can be converted to binary afterwards:

```rb
"0549~i~s"
|> :io_lib.format(~w[77 88])
|> to_string()
#⇒ "054988"
```

- `~i` stays for “ignore the next term”
- `~s` for treating the parameter as a binary

---

*Sidenote:* `io.format` *outputs* the formatted string to the IO device, returning `:ok`.